# Using the Ace Code Editor, can I have F3 have the same behavior as Ctrl+F?

Tags: jquery, search, key-bindings, ace-editor

I'm using the Ace Code Editor for a Chrome extension, details here:
http://ace.c9.io/

With the Ace Editor, Ctrl+F brings up a dedicated search element, while F3 just brings up the browser's native search element. Is there any way to have F3 function the same way as Ctrl+F? I've been trying with Ace's keybindings (and jQuery), but so far no luck.

The best I've come up with so far:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: 'f3search',
    bindKey: { win: 'F3' },
    exec: function(){
        var e = $.Event('keydown');
        e.which = 70;
        e.ctrlKey = true;
        $('pre.ace_editor').trigger(e);
    }
});
```

It just doesn't seem to apply the keybinding to load Ace's dedicated search. Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
  name: 'f3search',
  bindKey: { win: 'F3' },
  exec: function(){
    editor.execCommand("find")
  }
});
```